# why np.log need add a infinitesimal when calculate ln?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
def log_specgram(audio, sample_rate, window_size=40,
                 step_size=20, eps=1e-10):
    nperseg = int(round(window_size * sample_rate / 1e3))
    noverlap = int(round(step_size * sample_rate / 1e3))
    freqs, _, spec = signal.spectrogram(audio,
                                    fs=sample_rate,
                                    window='hann',
                                    nperseg=nperseg,
                                    noverlap=noverlap,
                                    detrend=False)
    return freqs, np.log(spec.T.astype(np.float32) + eps)
```

I saw this code on the github when I learn audio preprocess. This code convert audio to spectrogram. But I don't know why value need to add eps ( I think eps is a infinitesimal) and then called by np.log? What will this step do? It can make result  accurated? And I saw many this step on many other field.

Comment: To prevent taking the log of zero?

Answer (score 0):

`eps` is just a very small value. This is to prevent to take the log of zero, which would be `-inf`.